# How to use a forward slash to display a fraction?

Tags: math-mode, macros, fractions

Using `$\frac{x + 5}{y - 4}$` can make equations very long and difficult to read. I'd prefer to be able to write `$(x + 5)/(y - 4)$` and have it interpreted as `$\frac{x + 5}{y - 4}$`. How could I write a command that does this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\renewcommand\frac[2]{(#1)/(#2)}` ... But I don't really suggest this... (And it seems longer except if you mean "very tall").

Comment: @koleygr: I think OP is asking for the opposite of that: the usual output of `\frac`, but with just a slash in the TeX source.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It consists of two LaTeX macros, called `\InlineToDispOn` and `\InlineToDispOff`, and a Lua function called `inline_to_disp`. When activated via `\InlineToDispOn`, the Lua function scans all lines of input and replaces all instances of `(...)/(...)` with `\frac{...}{...}`. (The parentheses that encase the numerator and denominator terms are stripped off.)

Some additional comments:

- Use the macro `\InlineToDispOff` to deactivate the Lua function. This may be needed if your document has passages which much be reproduced *verbatim*.
- Nested matching parentheses in the numerator or denominator are ok, but only the outermost ones are processed. Hence, `(2(x+5))/(y-4)` will be transformed to `\frac{2(x+5)}{y-4}`.
- Whitespace to the left and right of the `/` division symbol is allowed.
- Per your write-up, the replacement operation *requires* both the numerator and denominator to be encased in pairs of matching parentheses.

  - By design, the Lua function `inline_to_disp` does *not* operate on expressions such as `x/y`, `(a)/b`, or `c/(d)`.
  - If you have an expression of the form `(x+5)/(y-4)` but do *not* want it to be changed to `\frac{x+5}{y-4}`, change it to, say, `(x+5){}/(y-4)`. The empty math group, `{}`, will assure that the `gsub` function inside `inline_to_disp` does not perform a successful match.
- Any number of instances of `(...)/(...)` may occur on a given input line. (See below for examples.)
- No input sanity checking of any kind is performed.

  - If the numerator and denominator terms are not syntactically valid from a LaTeX point of view and/or if the parentheses that encase the numerator and denominator terms are not matched, Latex will generate various mysterious warning and error messages.
  - The Lua function also doesn't check whether `(...)/(...)` occurs in (display or inline) math mode; if it occurs in text mode, Latex will crash with a comment that, you guessed it, `\frac` is not allowed to occur in text mode. This is, I trust, not much of a constraint since you're looking, in part, to replace various existing `\frac` expressions.

In the following screenshot, the upper row is typeset in `\textstyle`, while the lower one is typeset in `\displaystyle`:

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function inline_to_disp ( s ) 
  s = s:gsub ( "(%b())%s-/%s-(%b())" , function (u,v)
               u = u:sub(2,-2)  -- strip off the parentheses
               v = v:sub(2,-2)
               return "\\frac{"..u.."}{"..v.."}" 
           end )
  return s
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% LaTeX-side code:
\newcommand\InlineToDispOn{\directlua{%
  luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", 
  inline_to_disp, "InlineToDisp" )}}
\newcommand\InlineToDispOff{\directlua{%
  luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer", 
  "InlineToDisp" )}}
\AtBeginDocument{\InlineToDispOn} %activate by default

\begin{document}
$(x+5)/(y-4) \quad (x) / (y) \quad (2(x+5))/(y-4) \quad 2(x+5)/ (y-4) \quad x/y$

\bigskip
$\displaystyle % same as above, but now with \displaystyle instead of \textstyle
 (x+5)/(y-4) \quad (x) / (y) \quad (2(x+5))/(y-4) \quad 2(x+5)/ (y-4) \quad x/y$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand the OP's problem. The OP wants to substitute `$\frac{a}{b}$` with `${a}/{b}$ because the`\frac` macro is "difficut to read" (for the author, not the reader). Why not just use the forward slash?

```
% fracprob2.tex  SE 515788 Forward slash for fractions

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Inline math:
Some text $\frac{a}{b}$ more text $a/b$ that's it.

Displaymath:
\[
\frac{a}{b} , a/b 
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to write $a/b$ in the source, but have TeX interpret that as $\frac{a}{b}$.

Comment: @Teepeemm Maybe, but in general the forward slash rather than `\frac` gives a typographically better result.